# Ajax call Data not Binding

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to bind my form with modelattribute in controller throught ajax call but i didnt get the values in bean e.g all values of bean are null

I printed the form data in alert() its showing me correct data but in controller its showing me null

This is my ajax call and console.log() print whatever i want but in controller i am not getting my data.

Ajax call ::

```
function viewBugReport(data) {

    var formdata=$("#getAppForm_"+data).serialize();
    console.log(formdata);
        $.ajax({

            url : 'displaybugreport.html',
            data :formdata,
            processData : false,
            contentType : false,                
            type : 'POST',
            success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
            }
        });
}
```

Controller code ::

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/displaybugreport.html")
public String viewBugReport(@ModelAttribute BugReportBean1 bugreportbean, 
 HttpSession session) {


    String ResultMessage = "something went wrong!!";
    String adminId = "X";

    System.out.println(bugreportbean); 
    try {
        AdminBean adminBean = (AdminBean) httpSession.getAttribute(SESSION_KEY_ADMIN);
        adminId = adminBean.getUserId().trim();
         ResultMessage = bugReportService.submitBugReport(bugreportbean);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.debug("GADG:" + adminId
                + " :: Exception occured :: viewBugReort POST method :: BugReportController class");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ResultMessage;
}
```

Comment: did you try mentioning `HTTP`  Method: `@RequestMapping(value = "/displaybugreport.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)` ?

Answer (score 1):

As I can't see the full `controller` and you haven't mentioned any `HTTP` method in your desired `endpoint`, you can try like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/displaybugreport.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```